# Calling a https web service in node.js (Behind proxy)

Tags: node.js, https, proxy

I am trying to call a https web service from node.js. I am behind a proxy, so i am providing the proxy and port in the options along with the credentials. But i am getting the following error

`[Error: 2060:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:683:
]`

The following is the code snippet in which i am trying to call the https web service:

```
var https = require('https'); 
var username = 'username';
var password = 'password';
var auth = 'Basic ' + new Buffer(username + ':' + password).toString('base64');
var data = '';
var options = { 
hostname: 'proxy', 
port: 8080, 
path: 'https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/json/Leads/getMyRecords?authtoken=11111tsvs26677026bcba45ae3f&scope=crmapi',
headers: {
        "Proxy-Authorization" : auth
     }
};

console.log("options- " + JSON.stringify(options) + '\n');

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {

console.log("statusCode- " + res.statusCode);
console.log("headers-" + res.headers);

res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    data += chunk;
});

res.on('end', function (chunk) { 
    console.log('response-' + data);
});

});

req.end();

req.on('error', function(e) {
     console.error(e);
});
```

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance,
Manoj

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem by mistake using

```
var https = require('https');
```

But my proxy requires HTTP only, the proxy will in charge to complete the request HTTPS because you are setting it on path parameter

```
(...)
path: 'https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/json/Leads/getMyRecords?authtoken=11111tsvs26677026bcba45ae3f&scope=crmapi',
(...)
```

This works for me:

```
// baiken9: use http here
var http = require('http');

var username = 'username';
var password = 'password';
var auth = 'Basic ' + new Buffer(username + ':' + password).toString('base64');
var data = '';
var options = {
  hostname: 'proxy',
  // baiken9: Proxy Port
  port: 8080,  
  // baiken9: Add method type in my case works using POST
  method: "POST", 
  // baiken9: when proxy redirect you request will use https. It is correct as is
  path: 'https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/json/Leads/getMyRecords?authtoken=11111tsvs26677026bcba45ae3f&scope=crmapi',
  headers: {
    // baiken9: I cannot test it my proxy not need authorization
    "Proxy-Authorization" : auth,
    // baiken9: required for redirection
    host: "crm.zoho.com",
  // baiken9: length of data to send
    'content-length': 0
  }
};

console.log("options- " + JSON.stringify(options) + '\n');


var req = http.request(options, function(res) {

  console.log("statusCode- " + res.statusCode);
  console.log("headers-" + res.headers);

  res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    data += chunk;
  });

  res.on('end', function(chunk) {
    console.log('response-' + data);
  });

});

req.end();

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.error(e);
});
```

Ouput:

```
statusCode- 200
headers-[object Object]
response-{"response":{"error":{"message":"Invalid Ticket Id","code":"4834"}}}
```

Kind Regards

Comment: @BaikeN9Even my proxy requires http only. If that is the case how can i rectify this issue? Can you kindly help me to sort out this issue?

Comment: I have edit my answer and code was added with some comments explaining