# Call external rest api from node.js hosted in OPENSHIFT

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, https, openshift

I was trying to call a Google rest service from `nodejs` using `https.request`.

```
 https.request({
            host : 'www.googleapis.com',
            port : 443,
            path : '/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=accessToken',
            method : 'GET'
            }, function(res) {});
```

It is working fine locally. But when I hosted it on Openshift, 502 proxy error is coming up. I believe this because  of Openshift gear is working behind a proxy. Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459751/calling-a-https-web-service-in-node-js-behind-proxy

Comment: I am still not able to find a solution for this

Comment: @JithuRajan Any solution?